# WebClient and HttpWebRequest crashes while downloading big file on Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I've tried both WebClient and HttpWebRequest to download a file with size of 381MB through Wi-Fi connection or tethered. It kept crashes (no error nor exception). It works on a file with size 194MB. Any way to download big files? or Is there a limitation of file size to downlod on Windows Phone 7? Thanks.

For the HttpWebRequest: the Request.BeginGetResponse() never 'call back'; 
For WebClient: the DownloadProgressChanged is responding well, but it crashes before OpenReadCompleted.
The same code is working fine when file is smaller, such as, 194MB.

Here is the code for WebClient:

```
   WebClient wc = new WebClient();
   wc.DownloadProgressChanged += ((s, e) =>
   {
       UpdateProgress(e.BytesReceived, e.TotalBytesToReceive);
   });

   wc.OpenReadCompleted += delegate(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Error == null)
       {
           using (var storeIso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
           {
               if (e.Result.Length < storeIso.AvailableFreeSpace)
               {
                   if (storeIso.FileExists(LocalFilePath))
                      storeIso.DeleteFile(LocalFilePath);

                   using (var fs = 
                          new IsolatedStorageFileStream(LocalFilePath,
                          FileMode.Create, storeIso))
                   {
                      int bytesRead;
                      byte[] bytes = new byte[1024 * 1024 * 1]; // 1meg
                      while ((bytesRead = 
                         ResponseStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                      {
                        fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
                      }
                      fs.Flush();
                    }
               }
           }
       }
   };

   wc.OpenReadAsync(
    new System.Uri(DownloadFilePath, System.UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

Where UpdateProgress is to calculate the percentage.
When I tried on the file with size 381 MB, the app crashes before OpenReadCompleted is called.
It is similar when I tried the HttpWebRequest, the call back assigned to Request.BeginGetResponse() is not called for the file with size of 381MB.

For the smaller file size, it works just fine either with WebClient or HttpWebRequest. It seems to me there is 'memory' limitation in handing downloaded file to app?

Comment: can you post some code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are memory restrictions on the platform. Are you monitoring these? (See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/12/16/monitoring-memory-usage-on-windows-phone-7.aspx for details on how to do so.)

You will want to consider using multiple requests (with the `Range` header) to download large files. In addition to avoiding memory restrictions this will also allow your users to stop your app part way through the download and then restart it later without having to restart the download.
I've used this technique to download files up to 2.5GB on the phone.

Comment: @AwkwardCoder yes, over Wi-Fi. It's far from ideal/desirable but it can be done.

Comment: Would you be able to share some sample code of how you did this, or do you have a blog. That would be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

For large files (in my estimation anything over 3MB), be sure to set your `HttpWebRequest.AllowReadStreamBuffering = false`. This will get data moving.